# How to assign Sheet with Sheet CodeName in Google Sheets App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks for everyone's help on How to assign Sheet with Sheet CodeName in Google Sheets App Script. Like how to write the code below
case 1: assigning Sheet based on Sheet name, when the user changes the Sheet name, the code will fail.
Case 2: attaching Sheet based on the position of the Sheet in the Spreadsheet, when the user moves the position of the Sheet, the code will also fail.
In Microsoft Excel, there are 2 parts CodeName and SheetName, when calling Sheet with CodeName, the user's actions will not affect the code.

```js
function Sheet_CodeNam(){
   let Book=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   // Case 1
   let Sheet1=Book.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
   // Case 2
   let Sheet2=Book.getSheets()[1]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this method is included in your expected direction, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, I'm not sure whether this method is included in your expected direction, from your question, how about using the sheet ID? In the case of the sheet ID of Google Spreadsheet, even when the sheet name is changed and the sheet tab is moved, the sheet ID is not changed. I guessed that this might be your expected direction. But, when the sheet is deleted, the sheet ID is also removed. Please be careful about this.

The sheet ID can be retrieved from the URL of the Spreadsheet when you open the Spreadsheet with your browser. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts). For example, when the URL is `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/edit#gid={sheetId}`, `{sheetId}` of `gid={sheetId}` is the sheet ID.

When the sheet ID is used, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and set your sheet ID, and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetId = "###"; // Please set your sheet ID.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets().find(s => s.getSheetId() == sheetId);
  if (!sheet) {
    throw new Error(`Sheet ID of ${sheetId} was not found.`);
  }

  // do something
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log(values);

}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the Spreadsheet using the sheet ID.
- When the invalid sheet ID is used, an error like `Sheet ID of ${sheetId} was not found.` occurs.

#### References:

- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [getSheetId() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetid)